# Is there any possible way to change the publisher id for existing VSTS Extension?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I want to change the VSTS Extension publisher id. But while updating the VSTS Extension in market place I'm facing an error because publisher id has been changed. 
Below is the error we are seeing:

**Publisher ID 'NewId' provided in the extension manifest should match the publisher ID 'OldId' under which you are trying to publish the extension.**

Is there any possible way to update the existing extension with new publisher id?

Comment: Just wanted to check in before the weekend what the status on this issue was? Is below method could let you upload the extension successfully?

Comment: Changed the publisher name instead of publisher id.

Comment: We cannot change publisher Id, if we want to change publisher id like you suggested we have create new publisher and upload the extension which acts like new extension

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any possible way to update the existing extension with new
>   publisher id?

Of course it possible.

We do not limit the publisher id used. The error you received is caused by the **publisher which you defined in the manifest** is not same with **the login publisher name you are using**.

---

**Steps:**

**(1)** Just go this [page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/manage) and create a new publisher:

[image]

**(2)** And then, configure the publisher name.

**Note:** Here the publisher name you input **must same with** the new publisher name you are using in manifest.

[image]

---

As example, originally, I am using the publisher name `Merlin` to publish the extension. So, in my manifest, I defined it as below:

```
"publisher": "Merlin",
"version": "1.0.0",
```

Now, I want to change the publisher used as `mengdi`:

```
"publisher": "mengdi",
"version": "1.0.0",
```

At this time, I created the new publisher by using the above steps to upload my new extension successfully:

[image]